# How do I get rid of istart.webssearches.com?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, malware

I use Google Chrome search engine and I downloaded FLV viewer last week in order to watch a free film on line.  Now every time I open my computer and the internet via my Google Chrome icon, the Websearch search engine appears.

I have deleted all programs that appeared after downloading the FLV player but it keeps opening up every time I start my computer. I contacted Norton help line twice and have spent 2 hours each time while they remote controlled my system and tried to delete this.  Each time it looks like its gone but reappears the next day.  It was in my registry editor and in Google Chrome setting where they deleted it but it just reappears.  I want rid of it but don't know what to do.  I will have to go back to Norton but such a long process.  Hoping someone can help me here.  Thanks

Comment: Which version of Windows and Norton are you running?

Answer (score 0):

**How to delete istart.webssearches.com**

Windows 8:

- Slide mouse cursor across the desktop to bottom right corner.
- Click Settings on Charm bar when it appears, and then go to Control Panel.
- Select Uninstall a program and click to remove Webssearches
  Uninstaller.

Windows Vista & Windows 7

- Open Start menu and click Control Panel.
- Go to Uninstall a program and highlight Webssearches Uninstaller.
- Click Uninstall.

Windows XP

- Go to Start menu and click Settings.
- Open Control Panel and select Add or remove programs.
- Uninstall Webssearches Uninstaller.

**Remove istart.webssearches.com from browser**

Internet Explorer

- Press Alt+X and click Manage add-ons.
- Remove Quick Start from Toolbars and Extensions.
- Click Search providers.
- Set a new default search engine and then remove istart.webssearches.com.
- Press Alt+X again and click Internet options.
- Under General tab, rewrite your home page address and click OK.
- Restart browser.

Mozilla Firefox

- Press search engine icon on the left of search box.
- Click Manage search engines on drop-down menu.
- Remove istart.webssearches.com from the list and click OK.
- Press Firefox button and go to Options.
- Under General tab, rewrite your home page address and click OK.
- Next to "When Firefox starts" select "Show my homepage" and click OK.
- Click Firefox button again and go to Add-ons.
- Remove Quick Start from Extensions. Restart browser.

Google Chrome

- Press Alt+F and go to Tools.
- Click Extensions and remove Quick Start.
- Click Settings on the left.
- Select Open a specific page or set of pages under On Startup.
- Click Set pages, remove istart.webssearches.com and enter a new home page address. Click OK.
- Select Manage search engines under Search.
- Set a new default search engine, delete istart.webssearches.com and click Done.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, check your add-ons.

Secondly, you scan your computer with Malware Bytes available here: http://www.malwarebytes.org/